# document.write no escribe en la misma página

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba haciendo una página simple para practicar JavaScript, el script pide un dato y te devuelve la tabla de multiplicar de ese dato, no comprueba si es número ni nada. La cosa es que cuando le ingreso el dato y le doy a "Multiplicar" me escribe los resultados en otra página, cuando quiero que se escriban en la misma, debajo del input y del button.

Script:

```
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var result = num * i;
        document.write(num + " x " + i + " = " + result + "<br/>");
        //document.write("<br/>");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pruebas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="prueba.js"></script>
    <h1>Prueba de Scripts 1</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" nombre="num" id="num" placeholder="Tabla de multiplicar del...." size="18">
        <button type="button" onclick="multiplicar()">Multiplicar</button>
    </form>
    <br />
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 34);
    color: rgb(204, 210, 216);
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tengo entendido que que `document.write` se utiliza para escribir texto. Y en todo caso podrías usar el [append.child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Relacionado al comentario de @ang3les96: nunca está demás leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas *document.write* este ejecuta un *document.open* automaticamente por esto cuando ejecutas tu function te pasa a un nuevo documento.

para evitar esto podrías crear una etiqueta a la cual le pasaras tu resultado, así el render se hará donde tu especifiques.

cree un ejemplo para ti (pero hay mil maneras de hacerlo)

```js
 const $formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'),
      showResult = document.getElementById('resultado')

   $formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const num = e.target.num.value

      for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
         const result = num * i,
            span = document.createElement('span'),
            tamplateString = `${num} x ${i} = ${result}`

         span.innerHTML = tamplateString
         showResult.appendChild(span)
      }

   })
```

```html
 <h1>Prueba de Scripts 1</h1>
   <form id="formulario">
      <input type="text" name="num" placeholder="Tabla de multiplicar del...." size="18">
      <button id="btn_multiplicar">Multiplicar</button>
   </form>
   <div id="resultado" style="display: grid;"></div>
```

Comment: Si no te quedo muy claro el porque *document.write* se muestra en un documento nuevo, puedes seguir la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write